# onclick not happening if pagination is happening

Tags: javascript, php, html

my php code

```
<?php
  include 'dbConnect.php';  // include your code to connect to DB.


    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    //$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    echo $to11=trim($_GET['to']);
    $query = "select count(SRfeedback.ackNo)  as num from SRfeedback,tblRepairQueue where tblRepairQueue.ackNo=SRfeedback.ackNo and tblRepairQueue.ackNo like '".$locationprefix."%' 
    and DATE(tblRepairQueue.ClosedAt) >='".$from."' and DATE(tblRepairQueue.ClosedAt) <='2013-10-03' 
    and tblRepairQueue.repairStatus='Closed and Complete'" ;
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "ipad_xl.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;                                //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */

    $sql = "SELECT tblRepairQueue.ackNo as RAF ,tblRepairQueue.productDescription as PRODUCT , tblRepairQueue.customerName as CUSTOMER,tblRepairQueue.SR_id as ASSIGNED, SRfeedback.overall as OVERALL,SRfeedback.technical as TECHNICAL,SRfeedback.professionalism as PROFESSIONALISM,SRfeedback.response as RESPONSE,SRfeedback.quality as QUANTITY,SRfeedback.time as TIME FROM SRfeedback,tblRepairQueue where tblRepairQueue.ackNo=SRfeedback.ackNo and tblRepairQueue.ackNo like '".$locationprefix."%'
    and date(tblRepairQueue.ClosedAt) between '$from' and '2013-09-01' and tblRepairQueue.repairStatus='Closed and Complete' LIMIT $start, $limit";
    //$sql = "select tblRepairQueue.ackNo as RAF from SRfeedback,tblRepairQueue where tblRepairQueue.ackNo=SRfeedback.ackNo and tblRepairQueue.ackNo like '".$locationprefix."%' and DATE(tblRepairQueue.ClosedAt) between '".$from."' and '".$to."' 
    //and tblRepairQueue.repairStatus='Closed and Complete'  LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";   

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" style="outline:1px solid #CCC">
<tr style="background: url(../images/nav.png); color:#FFF; font-weight:600">
<td>overall</td>
<td>technical</td>
<td>Customer Name</td>
<td>Assigned</td>
<td>Overall</td>
<td>Technical</td>
<td>Professionalism</td>
<td>Response</td>
<td>Quality</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>

    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
        { ?>
    <tr  align="center" bgcolor="#E8F8FF" style="color:#006">
        <td><?=$row['RAF']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['PRODUCT']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['CUSTOMER']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['ASSIGNED']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['OVERALL']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['TECHNICAL']?></td>
         <td><?=$row['PROFESSIONALISM']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['RESPONSE']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['QUANTITY']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['TIME']?></td>
        </tr>

        <? }
    ?>

<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="../images/download.png" width="60" height="40" onClick="return download_file();"/></td>
<td align="center" colspan="9"><?=$pagination?>    </td></tr>
</table>



 <?
```

everthing works fine but my prob is

is not working when i immediately click on download image but after i do any pagination and click on download img its working.. can any one fix this issue

Comment: 'but after i do any pagination' does this mean like clicling on page number or next and prev ?

Comment: ya after clicking on page number then its working . but initially its not working

Comment: can you please post your download_file javascript function ??

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on "download image" calls a JavaScript function `download_file`, which is not present in this file.
I can only presume it is loaded separately, and is sometimes not available.

I strongly suggest you [open your developer tools console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console) before pressing on "download image".
When there's an error, it will be printed to your console and give you ideas on how to proceed further.